# How to find DNS server number for a static connection

Tags: windows-8

I tried to find my DNS so I could create a static connect, but it is the same as the default gateway. How would I find the DNS used in a static connection?

Comment: You really need to reword this to try and explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve.  It's likely to get heavily down voted otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using consumer-level network equipment, it is quite common for the default gateway to also handle DNS. To find out if this is the case, simply change the primary DNS server to the same address as the default gateway. If you can access google.com from your browser, it worked!

Otherwise, a quick fix **if you only require internet access** is to use Google's DNS server addresses. Their primary DNS address is 8.8.8.8, while their secondary DNS address is 8.8.4.4. Be aware, this method will sometimes break access to computers inside your network.

Answer (score 0):

From [your other question](https://superuser.com/questions/609279/how-to-find-a-dsn-server-on-windows-8-with-a-f9k1102v1-belkin-router), it really sounds like you're trying set up port forwarding.  In this case you need your internal and external IP address, and shouldn't need to touch DNS.

- For the external IP, just use a site like http://www.whatismyip.com/
- For the internal IP, use the IPv4 address returned by ipconfig